# Content query web part returns query returned a greater number of results than the web application's query throttling limit

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have a scenario to query all the lists and document libraries in my web application (entire site collection) and display all checked out items to me using query . This is been done and the problem is the web part is returning no items it pops up the message "Your query returned a greater number of results than the web application's query throttling limit. Please adjust the configuration of this Web Part or increase the throttling limit."
I did not apply any filters , no sorting is also done. I just added cal query in query string .I don't have any access to central admin to set the limit up. Any other ideas.Any suggestions on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot bend the rule, you have to abide. So if you cannot change the throttling limit, you *should* apply filters. E.g. get results in batches of 30 days

Comment: but in filters i don't see any option to add checked out to me . What ilter you want me to apple for?